# How to write a delete function for a binary tree in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn some Rust and started with implementing a binary tree. While doing insertions and in-order traversal seem easy enough I'm having some trouble with the borrow-checker in the delete method.

The code so far is:

```rust
use std::cmp::{Ordering, PartialOrd};
use std::fmt::Display;

struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Display + PartialOrd> Node<T> {
    fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            value: val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }

    fn print_inorder(&self) {
        print!("[");
        self.inorder(|x| print!("{}, ", x));
        print!("]\n")
    }

    fn inorder(&self, f: fn(&T)) {
        if let Some(ref x) = self.left {
            (*x).inorder(f);
        }
        f(&self.value);
        if let Some(ref x) = self.right {
            (*x).inorder(f);
        }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
        let mut node = self;

        loop {
            if val == node.value {
                return;
            }

            let child = match val.partial_cmp(&node.value).expect("Key comparison failed") {
                Ordering::Less => &mut node.left,
                Ordering::Equal => return,
                Ordering::Greater => &mut node.right,
            };

            match child {
                Some(ref mut c) => node = c,
                None => { *child = Some(Box::new(Node::new(val))); return}
            }
        }
    }

    fn delete(&mut self, val: T) -> bool {
        if self.value == val {
            unimplemented!{"Cannot remove root (yet) :/"};
        }

        let mut node = self;

        loop {
            if val < node.value {
                if let Some(ref mut c) = node.left {

                    if c.value == val {
                        if c.left.is_none() && c.right.is_none() {
                            // Error: cannot assign to node.left here
                            node.left = None;
                        }
                        else if c.left.is_some() && c.right.is_none() {
                            // Error: again cannot assign to node.left but cannot even access c.left
                            node.left = c.left;
                        }
                        else if c.left.is_none() && c.right.is_some() {
                            node.left = c.right;
                        }
                        else {
                            // TODO: walk through child tree and get rightmost element
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        node = c;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Node<T>>
}

impl<T: PartialOrd + Display> Tree<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
        match self.root {
            Some(ref mut n) => n.insert(val),
            None => self.root = Some(Node::new(val))
        }
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        match self.root {
            Some(ref n) => n.print_inorder(),
            None => println!("[]")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut t = Tree::<i64>::new();
    t.print();
    t.insert(14);
    t.print();
    t.insert(7);
    t.insert(21);
    t.print();
}
```

So in the `delete` method I cannot assign to the nodes I traversed downwards. But to delete a `Node` I have to assign a different value to its parent.

I found [this implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133209/binary-tree-implementation-in-rust?rq=1) but it doesn't compile for me (again with borrow-checker problems).

Comment: Are you committed to an iterative solution, or would you be happy with a recursive one? Recursion is _much_ easier in this instance.

Comment: I would also be happy with a recursive one. I just read that idiomatic rust was preferring iterative over recursive functions.

Comment: In general, iterative is better in many aspects: it's inure to Stack Overflows from deeply recursive data-structures, notably. On the other hand, it's prone to borrowing issues...

Comment: Right, but even with a recursive solution I was getting tons of borrowing issues, so I thought it wouldn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a recursive solution to dodge many of the borrowing issues that the iterative solution faces, as a starting point.

In order to be able to delete the root node, the key idea is to ask the `delete` function to return the *new* sub-tree rooted in the node; a slight modification is necessary in Tree, to harmonize things:

```rust
struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}
```

I added the `Box` layer, because `Node` contains `Option<Box<Node<T>>>`; this allows us handling root like another child node.

Then, I code the recursive `delete`:

```rust
fn delete(mut this: Box<Node<T>>, target: &T) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
    if target < &this.value {
        if let Some(left) = this.left.take() {
            this.left = Self::delete(left, target);
        }
        return Some(this);
    }

    if target > &this.value {
        if let Some(right) = this.right.take() {
            this.right = Self::delete(right, target);
        }
        return Some(this);
    }

    assert!(target == &this.value, "Faulty Ord implementation for T");

    match (this.left.take(), this.right.take()) {
        (None, None) => None,
        (Some(left), None) => Some(left),
        (None, Some(right)) => Some(right),
        (Some(mut left), Some(right)) => {
            if let Some(mut rightmost) = left.rightmost_child() {
                rightmost.left = Some(left);
                rightmost.right = Some(right);
                Some(rightmost)
            } else {
                left.right = Some(right);
                Some(left)
            }
        },
    }
}

//  Returns the rightmost child, unless the node itself is that child.
fn rightmost_child(&mut self) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
    match self.right {
        Some(ref mut right) =>  {
            if let Some(t) = right.rightmost_child() {
                Some(t)
            } else {
                let mut r = self.right.take();
                if let Some(ref mut r) = r {
                    self.right = std::mem::replace(&mut r.left, None);
                }
                r
            }
        },
        None => None
    }
}
```

Which is called from `Tree` via:

```rust
fn delete(&mut self, target: &T) {
    if let Some(root) = self.root.take() {
        self.root = Node::delete(root, target);
    }
}
```

The [complete code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=760b9e3d68c9cda33ef463248a7eba25) is available on the playground.

Comment: I guess the best way to merge subtrees would be replacing the deleted node with the leftmost child of its right subtree or the rightmost child of its left subtree (the nodes that come next to the deleted node in inorder traversal).

Could you also try to show how you would swap that node up to the current one?

Comment: Also what is the reason to use `fn delete(mut this: Box<Node<T>>)` instead of `(&mut self)` ?

Comment: As for the latter, note that it takes `Box<Node<T>>`, whereas `Self` is `Node<T>` only. By consuming and return `Box<Node<T>>` we avoid making allocations/deallocations for each function call -- and indeed should the value not be in the tree, not a single allocation or deallocation will occur.

Comment: Implemented merging, with no guarantee about algorithm soundness.

Comment: Great thanks! Just a quick addition:
The `(Some(left), Some(right)) => {` should now have a `Some(mut left)` pattern

Comment: @KillPinguin: Doh! Well spotted :)

Comment: Also testing the code I noticed that the merge implementation is indeed broken; The problem is that if the rightmost_child has some left children they need to be moved up to its parent.

Comment: Edit queue is full so here is the correct code for rightmost child:
`fn rightmost_child(&mut self) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
        match self.right.as_mut() {
            Some(r) => if let Some(t) = r.rightmost_child() {
                return Some(t)
            } else {
                let mut r = self.right.take();
                if let Some(ref mut r) = r {
                    self.right = std::mem::replace(&mut r.left, None);
                }
                return r;
            }
            None => None
        }
    }`

Comment: @KillPinguin: Indeed. That's the problem with algorithms, there are always edge cases.

Comment: `rightmost_child` is a bit obscure.